# Is there possible to convert QVector into Json string?

Tags: c++, json, qt, qvector, qjsonobject

I have struct type:

```
struct Book 
{
   int id;
   QString name;
   QString author;
}
```

And I read these from JSON text, and store them to `QVector<Book>` container.

How to convert this vector back to JSON text?

Comment: what *json string*?

Comment: @eyllanesc i mean, string with the type json

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the question as I understood it, to make it more clear. If I got it wrong, please roll back, or edit further!

Comment: @hyde sorry. Yes, you understood me right.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is supported by Qt 5, look at [JSON Support in Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html)

Comment: Yes, i know about it. I use it for convert string into Book type, but i did not find how to convert my container with objects to json. Especially, i want to know best practices with converting to json in qt.

Comment: @BogdanBabitskiy there is an example : _The JSON Save Game example demonstrates how to save and load a small game using QJsonDocument, QJsonObject and QJsonArray._ THis is all you need

Comment: oh, i forgot about the example)